# mysql_error strange behavior (return always empty string)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting this strange behavior:

Imagine you have a class that simply creates a connection to MySQL and returns the connection link.

```
class Connection {

    private $conn;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->conn = mysql_connect(.....);
    }
    public function getConn() {
        return $this->conn;
    }   

}
```

Now, if I try to use the connection link (of course instantiating Connection and using `$instance->getConn()`), I can use the link in the `mysql_query` function, but I cannot use it in `mysql_error` and `mysql_errno` (they always return respectively `''` and `0`, even if the query executed is absolutely wrong).

But!! If I place the link creation in the same class of the `mysql_query`, `mysql_errno` and `mysql_error`, all works perfectly!!

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Could you show an example of how you call `mysql_error`? Also doesn't get what's 'in the same class', that would be great to illustrate it as well. )

Comment: I will provide you an example!

Comment: Hi guys, I found that the problem was due to an error in my code. In particular there was a call to mysql_select_db between the mysql_query and the mysql_errno, so the last return always 0 because the was no error while selecting the db. However, thanks all!

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql
```

is deprecated, consider using

```
mysqli
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: This doesn't answer his question and should be a comment instead

Comment: The problem occured also with mysqli. However, Thank you!